# AngularJS Get result of of a http service when it done

Tags: angularjs

Im using AngularJS to get data from an API
I make a Service and Controller by Angular. I get data from service and use it from controller.
I have a Validation function for data input to check duplicated Key, and the service will do this by sending key entered to sever.
When click Save, from controller call the function Validate(), from Validate() call the service CheckExistedKey().
And I have a line like below

```
if(validate() == true){
    alert(''); //something to do
}
```

And the service like below

```
var defer = $q.defer();
var checkExistedKey = function (key){
    return $http.get('http://localhost:2807/api/Event/CheckExistedkey?key=' + key
        ).then(function (results) {
            defer.resolve(results.data);
            return defer.promise();
        });
}
```

But the alert is called before the validate() function.
I have put $q.defer in service, but nothing changed.
Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

In validate also you need to add callback function -

```
 function validate(){
    var deferredRequest = checkExistedKey ();
        deferredRequest.then(function (success) {
           return true;
        }
 }
```

See this - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/17r0mhp6/)

Comment: It still does not work. The result from validate() is undefined

Comment: `function validate() {
        var deferRequest = EventService.checkExistedKey($scope.Event.eventKey);
        deferRequest.then(function (result) {
            return result;
        });
}`

I nomalized all, so you can understand

Comment: I have updated answer.. please go through fiddle and you can follow same steps

Comment: Glad to help you.. Will you please accept the answer ?